# How to focus to the top of newly generated text in textView?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple jokes application. When you press the button you get new joke. If the previous one was bigger than the screen you can scroll it down. If you go down to the bottom and you go to the next joke, you are transfered to the bottom of the newly generated joke, but i want it to go to the top, and automatically display the start of the joke. How can i do this ?
I assume it would be done via the java code.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What component is it, and why have you put xml in the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [scrollTo(int x, int y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) method, i like to have ScrollView around my TextView but i think the same thing will work for a TextView only. hope you understand!

Rolf

**Example**

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="long\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n long\n\n\n\n\n\n\n very text here!" />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="joke" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**java:**

```
package org.sample.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AutoscrollActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button new_joke;
    private TextView joke;
    private ScrollView scroll;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new_joke = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        new_joke.setOnClickListener(this);
        joke = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text);
        scroll = (ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        joke.setText("Long\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n joke \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nlong joke joke");
        scroll.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```